# Why Ajax is not working in my page

Tags: php, ajax

Please help, ajax is not working..
I tried the tutorial from here, 
[Ajax box PHP](https://github.com/codeforgeek/ajax-box-php)
it works well, but when the code is installed in a different page, I just don't want to work.

here is codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>

<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
});
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/font-  awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/simple-line-icons.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/animate.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/datatables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="asset/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/select2/select2.min.css">
<!-- end: Css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="asset/img/logomi.png">
 </head>
  <body>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="bs-example">
        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
            </div>
        </div> 
   </div>
```

please help... thanks..

Comment: And are there any errors on the browsers console (F12)

Comment: "_I just don't want to work_" I know that feeling.

Comment: You're using a relative path for your remote, is it possible the new page is located elsewhere (and thus resulting in a 404)?

Comment: @kerbholz :D _it's not working_

Answer (score 0):

Please try by including the js and other bootstrap files first. And then try to execute the jquery and ajax code.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
</script>
```

Now it will works. Also make sure that all the js related files are included properly. While running the page in browser, type f12 and check the ajax call is generated or not.Hope it works.